# OpenGL in Qt Quick cross platform application

Tags: opengl, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtdeclarative

I'm trying to develop a cross platform (or at least desktop + embedded hardware) application. I would like to use Qt Quick to create a touch friendly GUI. I have been implemented a classical application with a QGLWidget displaying data. It is important that only a part of the window is in OpenGL. Because of this there are problems with EGLFS and LinuxFB. Only X11 (or maybe Wayland) can display the application properly (others generates a couple of errors about missing setParent function and the whole screen is black). Now I'm trying to achieve the same thing in QML. I want to use this OpenGL renderer as part of my QML application and some Qt Quick widgets around it. I found a couple of people asking about the same thing and the answer is always to subclass QDeclarativeItem and call the painter's beginNativePainting() (the others says to export it through QDeclarativeItem, but I cannot figure out how to do this). The problem is that on desktop, Qt 5.11 the native painter is not OpenGL. And in QT5 there is no way to force OpenGL graphics system. So when I try to get the OpenGL context (QGLContext::currentContext()) I always get NULL. Another problem: If I export my widget with qmlRegisterType("Test", 1, 0, "Test"); it becomes only visible when I use QDeclarativeView, but then it doesn't sees Qt Quick. If I use QQuickView it says module "Test" is not installed. How can I implement this properly?

Comment: I was able to draw to the window based on example under examples/quick/scenegraph/openglunderqml. BUT: Uniforms are corrupted every time when paint is called. Also I need multisampling to do antialising. Setting multisampling with window()->openglContext()->format().setSamples(4); simply doesn't do anyting...

Answer (score 0):

QDeclarativeItem is from Qt Quick 1 and Qt4. With Qt 5 and Qt Quick 2 you should use QQuickItem.
There is at least 1 example of this provided with qt docs, which you can find in Qt Creator in the Welcome tab in the Examples section.

Comment: Thank You, now I use QQuickPaintedItem and the OpenGL context is not NULL. But I cannot compile shaders with QOpenGLShaderProgram. I get an error when compiling vertex shader and the log is empty

Comment: Even worse, if I comment everything out and just clear the screen with black color, nothing happens. The widget remains the same color as the background. If I draw a rectangle with painter without beginNativePainting(), then it's ok. But unfortunately I need OpenGL.